# Swift 2, protocol extensions & respondsToSelector

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

I am not sure, it looks to me that it is some kind of bug or bad implementation with protocol extensions in Swift 2.0.

I have protocolA, protocolB extending protocolA and implementing methods in protocolB extension.

I have conformed an class instance to conform to protocolB, however when inspected by respondsToSelector for protocolA/B methods the results is false.

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground

protocol ProtocolA : NSObjectProtocol {
  func functionA()
}

protocol ProtocolB : ProtocolA {
  func functionB()
}

extension ProtocolB {
   func functionA() {
     print("Passed functionA")
   }

   func functionB() {
     print("Passed functionB")
   }
}

class TestClass : NSObject, ProtocolB {

    override init () {

    }
}

var instance:TestClass = TestClass()
instance.functionA() // Calls code OK..

if instance.respondsToSelector("functionA") {
    print("Responds to functionA") // **False, never passing here**
}

if instance.respondsToSelector("functionB") {
    print("Responds to functionB") // **False, never passing here**
}
```

Should be reported as a bug?

Comment: You should file a bug.

Comment: Yup. Did you file a bug already? :)

Comment: Yes, indeed it's a bug. Did you happen to file it?

Comment: I have filed a very similar bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-544

Comment: The reply to Nick's bug report above suggests this is a feature, not a bug, and will not be fixed. `respondsToSelector` does not work, and will not work, with protocol extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting. Looks like a bug to me. It does recognize functions on a class, but not on extension. No matter what type Instance has. Moreover without an extension code would not be compilable, since protocol methods are non optional. So really looks like a bug/feature? in responds to selector implementation.