# Respond to selector method in protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol{
    func xyz()->Void
}
extension SomeProtocol{

}

class SomeData:NSObject, SomeProtocol{
    func xyz()->Void{
        print("Match!")
    }
}

var s = SomeData()

s.respondsToSelector("xyz")
```

and thats work fine but I need to implement xyz() method in protocol extension, and then call with respondToSelector(), when I do this:

```
extension SomeProtocol{
    func xyz()->Void{
        print("Match!")
    }
}
```

then s.respondsToSelector("xyz") return **false**. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: could be a bug in the respondsToSelector implementation, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060365/swift-2-protocol-extensions-respondstoselector

Comment: Heh.. I need to respond to NSNotificationCenter selector methods in my protocol :/ I can't do this?